# While loop with an integer condition?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def gcd(x, y):
       while(y): x, y = y, x % y
       return x
```

The function above returns the greatest common divisor of two numbers.
Why is y used as the condition in the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in a `while` statement will be evaluated as a boolean.  An integer of `0` will evaluate to `False`, everything else will evaluate to `True`.

Your statement is equivalent to `while y != 0:`

Answer (score 1):

This is used because the `x % y` will reduce y to the remainder of x / y (also called modulo) with each iteration of the loop. So the loop will execute as long as y 'is true' or in other words as long as y has a value that is not `None` or zero.

Comment: Well, it's never going to be "null".  Python doesn't even have that.  "As long as y has a value that is not zero" would be more accurate.

Comment: My understanding is that null == 0 == False in Python but you are absolutely correct from a formal, mathematical perspective. So thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Python has `None`, but not "null".  If we're being picky, there are a whole set of things that are "false-ish", all of which work as Booleans.

Comment: Thanks, I edit the answer to be more accurate

Comment: Your latest edit isn't wrong (except for misspelling `None`) but it's a little misleading since there's no way `y` could be `None`.

Comment: @sog Your assumption that "null == 0 == False" is false, even if we use "None == 0 == False". You can check that with a simple `print(None == 0)`.

Comment: Thank you both for your clarification these are all really important points. I wish I could edit the comment but its probably best that I can't so that there is a record of my learning process. I guess I assumed that these would all be equivalent since ```while(None): print("stuff")```,```while(0): print("stuff")```, and ```while(False): print("stuff")``` all have the same result. But I see now that even though they all have the same result this does not translate to equivalence.  Thanks again, this was a very interesting and informative exchange, at least for me!